# Is there a program that allows you to write "pretty" library tutorials?

Tags: html

I need to write tutorial for a library I wrote. The tutorial should also include code.
I wonder if there is a platform/application that provides a nice option for writing such tutorials with code?

Comment: Hi @Erik Sapir are you looking to write publish the tutorial in HTML? Or is it something you wish to distribute printed / as a pdf etc?

Comment: It suppose to be a HTML tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest write your documentation in Markdown syntax and publish the file on Github.

Comment: Alternatively you can use something like [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to convert the Markdown to the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) might help (it generates documentation files from XML code comments (assuming whatever language your library is written in supports this)). Though I'd describe the output as functional rather than pretty.

Answer (score 0):

This pretty much depends on where and what format do you plan to publish your tutorial. For online publication (i.e. on a website, as HTML/CSS) you can use a [syntax highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/).